# Devices dropping off wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a TP Link TD W8951ND Router. Hard-wired to 1 PC and connected to my 16mbps internet connection.

Then I have on a regular basis 8 devices connected via WiFi ( 2 x iPhones, 1 x iPad, PS4, LG TV, 2 x Wireless Access Points connected to Satellite TV Boxes, 1 x Android Tumble)

This normally all works fine, however if friends/family come round with their own phones/tablets and connect to the wifi as well, it seems to kick off other devices. This happens literally every time, it just comes up with the message "Cannot connect to XXXX" when trying to connect.

There seems to be no logic to it, and I also have tiny drop-outs of connection too, which don't notice on most devices except for the PS4, if I'm playing online, usually once per session it will come up saying disconnected, and then will immediately reconnect.

I've checked my DCHP pool and there are 100 spaces, and I've also tried cycling between channels 1, 6 and 11 on my router, but nothing seems to make any difference?

Has anyone else got any ideas I can try please?

Thanks

Comment: Your router [may be running out of resources](http://superuser.com/a/721380/167187)